# Angular2 service iterate

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to get array from JSON API and then iterate it. I still can't understand how it works. Thank you for help.

This is how looks my service.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class PlayersService {
    roster:Roster[];

    constructor(private http: Http){
        this.roster = [];
    }


    getPlayer(id) {
       for (let player of this.roster) {
            console.log(player["id"]);
        }   
    }


    getRoster(season,category) {
        this.roster.push(this.http.get("http://API JSON LIST OF ID")
            .map(res => res.json()));
    }

}

interface Roster {
    id:number
}
```

This how I call it

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.getRoster();
   this.getPlayers();
}
```

Where is the fail please?

Comment: What part causes troubles? I don't see `subscribe()`. There won't be a push request without `subscribe()`

Comment: What is `this.getRoster()`? Shouldn't it be something like `this.myService.getRoster();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
@Injectable()
export class PlayersService {
    roster:Roster[];

    constructor(private http: Http){
        this.roster = [];
    }

    getPlayer(id) {
       for (let player of this.roster) {
            console.log(player["id"]);
        }   
    }

    getRoster(season,category) {
        return this.http.get("http://API JSON LIST OF ID")
       .map(res => res.json())
       .do(val => this.roster.push(val));  // the do operator should be used for side effects (eg modifying an existing array)
    }
}
```

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.playerService.getRoster().subscribe(val => this.playerService.getPlayer());
}
```